# libraries for external DSL evaluation in Scala

Tags: scala, dsl, parser-combinators, kiama

What are the steps required for evaluating an external DSL in scala, and what libraries are available for these?

After digging around i am able to create an AST out of case classes using parser combinators. What are the next steps in the process? I looked at kiama (https://code.google.com/p/kiama/) but it seems unclear from documentation ( may be due to my limited langauage processing knowledge ) how to maintain symbol tables, how to bind actions to dsl statements etc.

Comment: From my experience the learning curve of Kiama is indeed rather steep. However, it comes with lots of nice examples that illustrate, among other things, how to use symbol tables. I only implemented a frontend for a small language, but really enjoyed using Kiama.

Comment: Have you tried playing with the g8 template? https://github.com/inkytonik/kiama.g8

Comment: Kiama is beautiful. I worked only with the strategy-based term-rewriting module, but it was a enormous leg-up in working with first-order logic transforms.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that it would be good to have more tutorial-style documentation for common language processing tasks in Kiama. We are working on it, but I have nothing concrete to report at the moment.

In the meantime, all I can offer is the examples in the Kiama distribution. In particular, the minijava example is a reasonably accessible compiler for a non-trivial subset of Java. It does  name and type analysis (see SemanticAnalysis.scala) and generates JVM bytecode. The semantic analysis uses a simple model of passing around an environment from declarations to uses of names. Feel free to contact us here or on the Kiama mailing list if you have specific questions about how the example works.

The Oberon-0 example is also a complete compiler from an imperative language to C, including semantic analysis.

Comment: Thanks looking forward to it. Also i was unable to join the google group, which always responds of not having permission.

Comment: Sorry, just saw this message. The google group requires you to apply for membership to keep out spammers etc but I usually respond very quickly. Did you apply for membership?